# How to understand the initialization of a contract as an interface in Solidity

Tags: interface, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am learning SmartContract development on Ethereum with Solidity and I would highly appreciate your help to understand this one basic thing:

`KittyInterface` as a contract has no parameters, just one function:

```
contract KittyInterface {
  function getKitty(uint256 _id) external view returns (
    bool isGestating,
    bool isReady,
    uint256 cooldownIndex,
    uint256 nextActionAt,
    uint256 siringWithId,
    uint256 birthTime,
    uint256 matronId,
    uint256 sireId,
    uint256 generation,
    uint256 genes
  );
}
```

But then it gets initialized like this, giving one parameter (ckAddress).

```
address ckAddress = 0x06012c8cf97BEaD5deAe237070F9587f8E7A266d;
KittyInterface kittyContract = KittyInterface(ckAddress);
```

So my question is:

What happens when we call `KittyInterface(ckAddress)`; when the contract has no parameters to take, but only a function? Where does the "ckAddress" go?

Is the address taken to write/connect to the blockchain?
Or is it given to the first function of the contract?

It works, there are no errors, but I struggle to understand it.

It is part of the Cryptozombie-Course, so I cannot debug it.

Can anybody please help me understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the contract code is not available to us. The contract is
already deployed on a network and only its address is available to us. The only way to use such a contract is through low-level address-provided functions ( send, transfer,
staticcall , call , and delegatecall ). This is because we do not have the
definition of that contract and we cannot use the new keyword for it. If such a contract
implements an interface and that interface definition is available to us, we will be able to use it to reference the target contract through its address itself. with this

```
KittyInterface(ckAddress)
```

you are telling the compiler which functions are available in this deployed contract `ckAddress` so you can call those functions.

- Interface might not contain all the functions defined in the contract. Note that only functions defined within the interface are callable using this method: `KittyInterface(ckAddress)`

Answer (score 0):

The following part is not actual initiating, nor function calling.

```
KittyInterface kittyContract = KittyInterface(ckAddress);
```

It is just converting `ckAddress` to callable smart contract, when you know the type-signature of the function you want to call.

This is called [dependency-injection mechanism](https://www.zupzup.org/smart-contract-interaction/).

More info can be found in the link.